# Install wicd on Slackware 14.1

Tags: software-installation, python, slackware, wicd

I am trying to install wicd-1.7.2.4 on Slackware 14.1. I couldn't find `configure` or `makefile` in `wicd-1.7.2.4.tar.gz`.

Running `python setup.py configure` (following the INSTALL guide) causes:

```
sh: pybabel: command not found
```

Then I tried to install `pybabel` but couldn't find sources and libraries. How can I install `wicd`?

Comment: You do realize that Slackware has NetworkManager installed by default? Properly configured it should do most, if not all of what you need.

Comment: Default manager doesn't find any ssid. I think there is a problem with my network card. However I am just curios About installing wicd on slackware.

Comment: Have you tried install it from the `/extra` directory included in Slackware official DVD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wicd is included into Slackware official ISO file, so you don't need to compile it. Here's an installation's step by step:

1. Download it, using `wget`:

   ```
   $ wget http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware-14.1/extra/wicd/wicd-1.7.2.4-i486-4.txz
   ```
2. Become superuser, type `su` in a terminal, i.e. `xterm`.

   ```
   $ su
   ```
3. And install it with `installpkg`.

   ```
   # installpkg wicd-1.7.2.4-i486-4.txz
   ```

Now, you can use:

```
# chmod -x /etc/rc.d/rc.networkmanager
```

to disable the NetworkManager daemon at start time. After that, just restart your beautiful operating system and enjoy it!